# Database design for unilateral relationship between contractors and companies

Tags: database, database-design

Companies and contractors can have contacts, those contacts can be both companies and contractors, and that relationship is unilateral (no need for the other party to accept).

I was thinking of doing something like this:

Contacts:

| ContractorId | CompanyId | ContactContractorId | ContactCompanyId | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | 15 | NULL | 3 |
| NULL | 22 | 12 | NULL | 1 |
| NULL | 44 | NULL | 22 | 2 |

ContactTypes:

| Id | Type |
| --- | --- |
| CompanyToContractor | 1 |
| CompanyToCompany | 2 |
| ContractorToContractor | 3 |
| ContractorToCompany | 4 |

Is this a good approach, or should I create four different tables, one for each type of relationship?

Comment: What do your base tables look like? Do you have a table of contractors, a table of companies, and a table of contacts? Or are your contacts just a link table from company/contractor to company/contractor? You should be able to get away with the one link table, so long as your foreign key relation is nullable. If you can't nullify it, then you would need the four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model doesn't require companies and contractors to be handled differently, use a generic table that covers both.  Otherwise you could do first 3 columns of the above like this:

```
contact: contact_id

company: company_id, ...
company_contact: company_id, contact_id

contractor: contractor_id, ...
contractor_contact: contractor_id, contact_id
```

and for the last 2 columns:

```
contact_company: contact_id, company_id
contact_contractor: contract_id, contractor_id
```

which would enable referential integrity.

If you don't care about the foreign keys, use unique key across both company and contractor tables.  For example a sequence or an uuid.  This would would allow you your contractor to have  reference to either table table and eliminate the company_contact and contractor_contact.  Similar, you can condense contact_company and contact_contractor into 1 table.